# How l can load databases in memory

Tags: java, mysql, sql, performance, select

I have a problem with performance of my program.I have a java program that connect to MySql database and do some process witch depend execute SELECT query on database.

Now problem is that my program for process have to execute 130,000 select query on mySql and this need a long of time.

I have 10 minutes for do all process.

Have any idea how do execute 130000 select query maximum in 10 minutes?

Comment: Please post some data structure. In general, adding proper indices would help speeding up the queries.

Comment: 130,000 SELECTs are a lot, are you sure you really need that large number? I would try to optimize my logic to lower that number. No offense, but especially mysql users might have not much expertise in SQL and try to solve problems in an inefficient way. Could you elaborate on the actual SELECTs?

Comment: @dnoeth I have a tree of nodes with prefix like '12', '120', '1201', '1202' and etc. I need to use select query for get parent of each node and make tree.In other word I wrote a select query that execute this for each node return parent of node and I save parent id in node.Now my tree have 130000 nodes and I have to execute my select query for 130000 times.

Comment: You seem to need some kind of recursion and mysql doesn't support recursive queries. But every recursion can be rewritten using WHILE-loops and there are Stored Procedures in mysql. If the maximum level within your tree is known you might be able to do it with a single SELECT. Can you show the existing SELECT + Java logic?

Comment: To get the parent of a node you can join using LIKE, now it depends on the rules how this tree is created. E.g. if the next level adds a single digit to the previous: `select 
   t1.*,
   t2.*
from tab as t1 left join tab as t2
  on t2.node like t1.node || '%'
 and t2.node <> t1.node
 and char_length(t2.node) = char_length(t1.node) + 1`

Comment: @Punkbf Do not just answer in comments (they disappear), [edit] your question to include all essential info. And add data structures and queries.

Comment: Once you have read all 130K rows, they will be cached in RAM.  Or do you not have much RAM?  Or did you not tune adequately?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (as an Edit to your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Have any idea how do execute 130000 select query maximum in 10 minutes?

It's a 200 queries per second, this should be doable for simple queries. However, the simplest solution is probably to replace them by a single query loading all needed data (you're already assuming that it fits in memory) and process it in Java.

As a `HashMap` is orders of magnitude faster than any database, the task will become trivial and your machine gets bored.

Answer (score 0):

One Approach is to use InMemory databases Like H2 or HSQL. This Solution will work only if you can pre-load data into memory. Lot of other factors also need to consider like Volume of Data , Frequency of Changes in data in the database etc.

If this is possible, then you can query directly in Memory, which is always faster.

1. Identify the important data to be loaded to Memory
2. Create corresponding table structure in Memory DB like H2 Or HSQL
3. Load those data from your actual MySQL and Insert this in Memory DB
4. Fire Query in that DB

Comment: tanks my friend.Your approach is so close to solution in my mind.but can you explain more how do this exactly?

Comment: Really use hsql or h2 can execute 130000 select query in 10 minutes?

Comment: You can write a test case and test the same. I didn't tried. But I used both and are super sonic speed and meet our requirements.